# asp.net bundler "webpage/content/js" not found

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, razor, bundles

I just browsed through tons of googled pages to solve this problem, but it looks like that each of it is unique. My page source shows that the pack is bundled in the way that it should work

```
 <script src="/Content/js?v=N2f3Y-Z24wBpC67A34qPxjK1CR3eY83Yijs13VtHOwI1"></script>
```

,but the browser(chrome) dev tool indicates that it failed to load it:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:53608/Content/js/
```

And, and also I get microsoft generated message that resourse is missing or not found if i click on script src link as well.

I get other bundles (styles) to load alright, I guess, I missed something in my code layout, and I cant find the problem myself. I'd be really grateful if any of you could point my mistake there, so here goes the code:

_Layout.cshtml

```
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

BundleConfig.cs

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js",//(tried other numbers as well)
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*",
                    "~/Scripts/itpoverlay.js"
                    ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").
            Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            //"~/Content/ie.css",
            "~/Content/kwicks-slider.css",
            "~/Content/style.css",
            "~/Content/custom.css",
            "~/Content/responsive.css",
            "~/Content/touchTouch.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/js").Include(
          "~/Content/js/bootstrap.js",
          "~/Content/js/forms.js",
          "~/Content/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js",
          "~/Content/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js",
          "~/Content/js/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.js",
          "~/Content/js/jquery.preloader.js",
          "~/Content/js/superfish.js",
          "~/Content/js/jquery.js",//(default bundle v1.8.1)
          "~/Content/js/touchTouch.jquery.js"));
       BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

_references.js (I literally have no idea why it's there)

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.9.1.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-ui-1.10.4.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
/// <reference path="knockout-2.1.0.debug.js" />
/// <reference path="modernizr-2.5.3.js" />
```

Now for the output, the bundles look well generated:

```
    <link href="/Content/css?v=NASaW-JeM0CkSMQIcoasDpn9k7bKaEK07c7WakA1Y0k1" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/Content/js?v=N2f3Y-Z24wBpC67A34qPxjK1CR3eY83Yijs13VtHOwI1"></script>
    <script src="/bundles/jquery?v=VwkJeyosUZnIv9pTtkEir1OOQCcR7BXo1RW8kdleacU1"></script>
```

And the dev tool marks list of the errors (I think, I'm starting to get what that _reference.js might be used for) Should it be bundled as well? The errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:53608/Content/js/
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' jquery?v=VwkJeyosUZnIv9pTtkEir1OOQCcR7BXo1RW8kdleacU1:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:53608/js/jquery.preloader.js
```

I hope it's enought to spot my mistake, and if there is something unclear, I'll happily update the question with required information.
Thanks, Ernis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery live method was deprecated in 1.7, and it looks like you are using 1.9

```
https://api.jquery.com/live/
```

So it looks like you have two options. Figure out where you are using the live method, and change it to use .on(). I can't give you specific code, because I don't know how you are using .live()

or look into using jquery migrate

```
http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/
```

Comment: Thanks for the note, i think this is it, but the .live is used in
   _jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js_
   _jquery.flexslider-min_
that are the default sripts included in template project on which my website is built, the loader overlay never dissapears, that's the problem, so only migrate solution remains right?

Comment: Jup migrating helped, also i solved that content/js found problem by using scriptsbundle.includeDirecotory("~/content/js","*.js")
A big thanks to you, I really thought the problem were elswhere.